# Is it possible to access to the admin page once the application is uploaded to the internet? | Django

Tags: django, admin

I'm very new on django and I want to ask just a simple question: in the developing phase, I can easily access to the admin page of django. I'm wondering if this is still possible to do when the website will be uploaded.

I'm sorry for the trivial question, hope you will help me.

Comment: Yes, just use the new server name with the path you assigned to admin like ~~~http://your_server/admin/ .... please be aware that for security reasons it is recommended to not use the /admin/ as path as used in the django standard setup but change it to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can access it. You can also create superusers in production.
However, it's not recommended and normally we change /admin/ for another URL (mainly for safety reasons).

Comment: URLs can easily be dirbusted even if you change the URL.